# Website display fast in browser but Timeout in Google Speed Site

Tags: pagespeed

I've an issue since fews days. When I test my website, I've this error :
Timeout while fetching the main resource. Ensure that the page loads in a browser and try again.

If I test my website in a browser, it's ok and very fast.

My website : www.artdeseduire.com

And this error append on every of my web sites. ( ex : www.bluesteel.fr )

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've just run your site through webpagetest.org and it seems that it takes a while to load. You can see the results here:

https://www.webpagetest.org/result/170608_J0_159D/

It appears as if you are loading around **50** or so images just on the home page. The page is also about **5 MB** in weight which is causing the page to load slowly. This could be the cause of the Google Pagespeed timing out!

Remember, just because it is fast on a broadband connection - doesn't mean it will be fast for *real* users out there!

Some things you could consider:

- Reducing the number of images on the page
- Lazy loading the images
- There are around 15 JavaScript files on the page, you could combine and minify these - also, do you need all of them?

Those are just a few things, but hope that helps!

Comment: I've test with a similar website of mine like gabriellemoore.com and no timeout with a 0 by Google. It have the same weight of mine (maybe more)

Comment: Problem is gone to night. Why? No idea :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your router/modem, it can be blocking the port. Try to use another network and see if that is still happening.